# Date validation fails because of date format I guess

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, scripting

I have the following regex which validates dates:

```
//are not both dates
if (!methods._isDate(first[0].value) || !methods._isDate(second[0].value)) {
    return options.allrules[rules[i]].alertText +   
           options.allrules[rules[i]].alertText2;
}
```

Regex below :

```
_isDate: function (value) {
             var dateRegEx = new RegExp(/^\d{4}[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$|^(?:(?:(?:0?[13578]|1[02])(\/|-)31)|(?:(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])(\/|-)(?:29|30)))(\/|-)(?:[1-9]\d\d\d|\d[1-9]\d\d|\d\d[1-9]\d|\d\d\d[1-9])$|^(?:(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])(\/|-)(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8]))(\/|-)(?:[1-9]\d\d\d|\d[1-9]\d\d|\d\d[1-9]\d|\d\d\d[1-9])$|^(0?2(\/|-)29)(\/|-)(?:(?:0[48]00|[13579][26]00|[2468][048]00)|(?:\d\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26]))$/);
             return dateRegEx.test(value);
         },
```

But this looks like for mmddyy, and my date is always ddmmyy.

Can you rewrite this regex? Please check it.

Comment: StackOverflow is a community for answering questions, not a "fix this code for me" service. You _did_ ask a specific question, but I doubt the answer would be of any use to you.

Comment: what change i need to do here?

Comment: If you're working with regular expressions, you _should learn_ regular expressions instead of looking for somebody to do your work for you. If you already know regular expressions, you should be able to rewrite the expression yourself instead of looking for somebody to do your work for you. _At the very least_, you should google for a regular expression that does what you need.

Comment: [0-3][0-9][/](([0][0-9])|([1][0-2]))[/][0-9]{4} I got it myself please upvote my question

Comment: Your question is still bad, answering it yourself does not make it any better. You can post an actual answer yourself and accept it. Still won't make it a good question though.

Comment: I can do it only after 8 hours ..please upvote me :-(

Comment: Your regex would match date `39/12/0000` - what date is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*For **DDMMYYYY**, with optional leading `0` for day and month, separators `/` or `-`, years `1900`-`2099`, without checking validity of `29.`, `30.` or `31.` day in month it would be:*

```
/^(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-](19\d{2}|20\d{2})$/
```

*To use just 2-digit year format go with:*

```
/^(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-](\d{2})$/
```